# How to access columns of subqueries with jooq?

Tags: mysql, jooq

i am having troubles understanding how to access columns from a subquery (MySQL). Here is my code:

```
Personne personne = Personne.PERSONNE.as("personne");
Evenement evenement = Evenement.EVENEMENT.as("evenement");
Genealogie genealogie = Genealogie.GENEALOGIE.as("genealogie");
Lieu lieu = Lieu.LIEU.as("lieu");

SelectField<?>[] select = { DSL.countDistinct(personne.ID).as("countRs"), lieu.LIBELLE.as("libelleRs"),
lieu.ID.as("idVille") };

Table<?> fromPersonne = evenement.innerJoin(personne).on(personne.ID.eq(evenement.IDPERS))
.innerJoin(genealogie).on(genealogie.ID.eq(personne.IDGEN)).innerJoin(lieu)
.on(lieu.ID.eq(evenement.IDLIEU));

Table<?> fromFamille = evenement.innerJoin(personne).on(personne.IDFAM.eq(evenement.IDFAM))
.innerJoin(genealogie).on(genealogie.ID.eq(personne.IDGEN)).innerJoin(lieu)
.on(lieu.ID.eq(evenement.IDLIEU));

GroupField[] groupBy = { lieu.ID };

Condition condition = //conditionally build, not relevant i think

result = create.select(DSL.asterisk())
                    .from(create.select(select).from(fromPersonne).where(condition).groupBy(groupBy)
                            .union(create.select(select).from(fromFamille).where(condition).groupBy(groupBy)))
                    
// i would like something like this but i don't know how:  .groupBy(groupBy).fetch();
```

Basicly what i have is:

```
SELECT
*
FROM(

(SELECT
countRs, libelleRs, idVille
FROM
fromPersonne
WHERE
-- conditions
GROUP BY lieu.ID)

UNION 

(SELECT
countRs, libelleRs, idVille
FROM
fromFamille
WHERE
-- conditions
GROUP BY lieu.ID)

)GROUP BY lieu.ID -- this is where i need help
```

In a plain MySQL query i would just give an alias to the union and then make a reference to the column i want to `group by` using the alias but it seems like it does not work like this with JOOQ.
I just need to group the results of the subqueries together but i don't know how to make a reference to the subqueries columns... I am sure i would have to reference my subqueries in objects outside of that "main select" to be able to access the columns or something along those lines but i am lost in all  the object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign your derived table to a local variable and dereference columns from it, e.g.

```java
Table<?> t = table(
  select(...).from(...).groupBy(...).unionAll(select(...).from(...).groupBy(...))
).as("t");

Field<Integer> tId = t.field(lieu.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you definitely are everywhere!